# How to reference a dictionary in another project WPF

Tags: xaml

[Custom Control Wpf Library]

```
Test
-->Resources
    -->Resources
       -->Dictionary1.xaml (Reusable across multiple project)
       -->Dictionary2.xaml(Reusable across multiple project)
```

[WPF main UI] TestRD

```
-->Resources
    -->Resources
       -->Dictionary9.xaml(Specific to the project)
```

XAML:
Dictionary1.xml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush" Color="Red"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dictionary2.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush" Color="Green"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dictionary9.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!--How can I use the resource from another DLL here-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

1. How can I reference Dictionnary1 or dictionary2 in Dictionary9?
2. Is it advisable, especially in a modular project?

I have some styling I would like to move globally so I can reuse and stop copy and pasting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How can I reference Dictionnary1 or dictionary2 in Dictionary9?

Try this:

**Dictionary9.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!--How can I use the resource from another DLL here-->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Resources/Dictionary1.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Resources/Dictionary2.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note that the 1st "Resources" is your lib name and the 2nd "Resources" is the folder name inside your lib.
You can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-use-an-application-scope-resource-dictionary?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

> 2. Is it advisable, especially in a modular project?

IMO, is totally OK if you're reusing or need to separate these dictionaries.